# Invalid AdWords gclid error in analytics

Tags: magento-1.9

I am running adword campaign and getting gclid error along with less sessions then clicks coming to site.
My magento version is 1.9.0.1

somehow the gclid is maintained on home page but redirects and remove it on products and inner pages, even the CMS and category and product pages.

I have tried all the solutions available online like https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento-Redirect-Loses-URL-Querystring/td-p/4608
but without luck.

I also tried adding a query string like ?mytag=123 and hat too redirects and removes it

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I would appreciate the help.